# How to deal with $g(f(x))$ in the limit?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$. Does the following hold as $x\to\infty$?:
$$\exp(x) \leq \exp\left({\frac{x}{1+1/\ln(1+f(x))}}\right)$$

**My effort:** If above inequality holds in the limit, the it must be that the following holds in the limit (take $\log$ of both sides): 
$$x \leq {\frac{x}{1+1/\ln(1+f(x))}}$$
Or, equivalenty:
$$1/{\ln(1+f(x))} \leq 0$$
which is valid since $f(x)\to \infty$ (given in the problem statement), and thus $1/{\ln(1+f(x))} \to 0$. So, the inequality in the problem statement holds in the limit.

Is this thought process correct? If not, please provide me with a correct proof if the inequality above holds or does not hold for all $f(x)$ that tend to infinity as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I think I understand what you're confused about. Usually, when people talk about an inequality holding in the limit, what the mean is that it is true for all sufficiently large $x$, which you can easily show is false for this problem

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that, since exp function is increasing

$$e^x \leq e^{\left({\frac{x}{1+1/\ln(1+f(x))}}\right)}\iff x \leq {\frac{x}{1+1/\ln(1+f(x))}}$$

and since eventually $x>0$, $1+f(x)>1$ we have

$$x \leq {\frac{x}{1+1/\ln(1+f(x))}} \iff \frac1{\ln(1+f(x))} \le 0$$

which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with your reasoning comes when you claim
$$
1/\log(1+f(x)) \le 0
$$
Since $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$, this means that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ sufficiently large. When $f(x) > 0$ however, we would have that $1/\log(1+f(x)) >0$ because $\log(z) > 0$ whenever $z > 1$.

All the other steps in your reasoning are correct, so in fact the answer is that the inequality is false for large $x$.

The point you seem to be confused on is the fact that 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} 1/\log(1 + f(x)) \le 0
$$
which is true, but is not good enough to make the original inequality true. Why? Because both sides go to infinity, so even though the $1/\log(1 + f(x))$ is trying to go to $0$, since it is strictly positive it can still affect the rate at which the function $\exp(\frac{x}{1 + 1/\log(1 + f(x))})$. For example, suppose $f(x) = x - 1$. Clearly, that goes to infinity. You would therefore be claiming that in the limit
$$
\exp(x) \le \exp\left(\frac{x}{1 + 1/\log(1+f(x))}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{x}{1 + 1/\log(x)}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{x\log(x)}{\log(x) + 1}\right)
$$
but the left hand side goes to infinity much faster than the left. If we take the ratio of both sides, you would claim:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\exp(x)}{\exp\left(\frac{x\log(x)}{\log(x) + 1}\right)} &\le& 1 \\
\exp\left(x - \frac{x\log(x)}{\log(x) + 1}\right) &\le& 1 \\
\exp\left(x\left(1 - \frac{\log(x)}{\log(x) + 1}\right)\right) &\le& 1 \\
\exp\left(x\left(\frac{1}{\log(x) + 1}\right)\right) &\le& 1
\end{eqnarray}
but the right hand side goes to infinity in the limit.

Comment: Thanks. I\f you don' believe my argument is correct, can you provide me with a correct one?

Comment: Just use your same argument until you get to the step $1/\log(1 + f(x)) \le 0$.

Comment: what should I do instead of the step you mentioned?

Comment: The limit of $f(x)$ being positive infinity implies that $1/\log(1 + f(x)) > 0$ for large $x$ so the original inequality is false because it would imply $1/\log(1+f(x)) \le 0$

Comment: I agree, $1/\log(1+f(x))>0$, but $1/\log(1+f(x))$ can get as close as desired to zero, and it becomes zero as $x \to \infty$. That fixes it.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but for any finite $x$ the inequality is false. $1/\log(1 + f(x))$ going to 0 is not strong enough to make the original inequality hold. In fact, you can show that $\frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(x/(1 + 1/\log(1+ f(x)))}$ goes to $\infty$ in the limit.

Comment: But, I needed the inequality to hold only in the limit, not for all finite $x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81155/discussion-between-dark-malthorp-and-susan-math123).

Answer (score 0):

Your thought process is rather tricky, as your last line holds exactly in the limit of $x\to\infty$, and is wrong for all other $x>0$.

You however start your deduction from the desired result and move backwards - which is okay, as every step you make is bijective for sufficiently big $x$, but to make conclusions about the bijectivity of your steps regarding a limit, you need to prove that the limit exists (remember, all those rules one learns require this).

This is not given in your proof, as e.g. $lim_{x\to\infty} exp(x) = \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. But, can you tell me more clearly?  I only need it to hold when $x$ tends to infinity.

Comment: And your argumentation doesn't provide this result.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of this process is reversible so your method is right but we have $$\dfrac{1}{\ln{1+f(x)}}\le 0\leftarrow\rightarrow\ln{1+f(x)}< 0$$which means that $$f(x)<0$$so it doesn't hold under your constraints.

Comment: Thanks, but the right side of your first equation is missing "f(x) to \infty". Wouldn't that fix my argument?

Comment: Also, if you don' believe my argument is correct, can you provide me with a correct one?

Comment: Your way is correct and this question would be satisfied using your constraint if $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=\infty$$

Comment: I have said what you need at the beginning of my problem statement.

Comment: In other words, I said in my problem statement that $f(x)$ tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. So, my argument should be correct. Right?

Comment: Yes absolutely but take for example $f(x)=e^x-1$ then your inequality reduces to $$e^x\le e^{\frac{x^2}{x+1}}$$which is absolutely wrong for large $x$